# Recording audio in Django model

Tags: django, django-models

Hey i would like to record an audio as a voice note in one of my models:

```
class ShipPhoto(models.Model):
    user_name      = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo          = models.ImageField()
    voice_record   = ??????
    carplates      = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

So that when i open the form_template i can click the voice record and upload the recorded message to my model. I've checked this link https://github.com/voxy/django-audio-recorder but when i install it using pip command it automatically uninstalls my current version of django (2.0.8) and downgrades to 1.8 ... Is there any other solutions how can i do it ??

====================================================================
UPDATED (10/10)

Still not sure how could i incorporate videojs in my Django Form. Below you can see my ModelForm, views.py and template.

ModelForm

```
class ShipPhotoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ShipPhoto
        exclude= ('user_name',)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not obj.pk:
            obj.user_name = request.user
        obj.save()
```

views.py

```
class ShipPhotoCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    login_url = '/accounts/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'

    form_class = ShipPhotoForm
    template_name = 'photo/shipphoto_form.html'

    def create_object(self, audio_file):
        return self.model.objects.create(**{self.create_field: audio_file})

    def get(self, request):
        form =self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})

    def post(self,request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print(form.errors)
        if form.is_valid():  # uploader has been excluded. No more error.
            photo = form.save(commit=False)  # returns unsaved instance
            photo.user_name = request.user
            photo.save()  # real save to DB.
            return redirect('photo:main')
        return render(request,self.template_name,{})
```

template

```
{% extends "main/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% include "form_template.html" %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit/上传</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

"form_template.html"

```
{% for field in form %}
 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <span class="text-danger small">{{ field.errors }} </span>
    </div>
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">{{ field }}</div>
 </div>

{% endfor %}
```

Could i overwrite the `{{field}}` for `shiphoto.voice_record` so that it works with .js plugin or sth like that. I am not quite sure how to add the .js script to my template so that when opening the ShipPhotoCreate(View) and clicking the `voice_record` field it would prompt my cellphone to open a voice record and then save it in the data base.

Comment: In essence it is just a `FileField`, and it also defines a view and widget: https://github.com/voxy/django-audio-recorder/tree/master/audio_recorder

Comment: django-audio-recorder is obviously not maintained anymore - hasn't been updated for 2 years and doesn't support django > 1.9 (according to the last commit message) or 1.8 (according to what you report). If you want to use it you'll have to fork the repo and migrate the app to django 2.x.

Answer (score 4):

In models

```
voice_record = models.FileField()
```

Use some js plugin to record audio on client side. I personally use [videojs](https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record) as it can do both audio and video. Then send the recorded audio file to server and save it. I personally use ajax, you can use any method.

In views:

```
audio_file = request.FILES.get('audio')
shipphoto_obj = ShipPhoto.objects.get(pk='whatever')
shipphoto_obj.voice_record = audio_file
shipphoto_obj.save()
```

**Complete Code:**
*Template*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'myapp/videojs-record/dist/css/video-js.min.css' %}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'myapp/videojs-record/dist/css/videojs.record.min.css' %}" />

<style>
    /* change player background color */
    #myAudio {
        background-color: #9FD6BA;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <audio id="myAudio" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"></audio>
    <button class="audio-btn strt disable-btn" id="submit" disabled>Submit</button>
    <span class="upload-comp">Uploading Complete</span>

<!-- Requires a lot of external js, I think I have added them all. -->
<script src="{% static 'myApp/videojs-record/video.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'myApp/videojs-record/RecordRTC.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'myApp/videojs-record/adapter.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'myApp/wavesurfer/dist/wavesurfer.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'myApp/wavesurfer/dist/plugin/wavesurfer.microphone.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'myApp/videojs-wavesurfer/dist/videojs.wavesurfer.min.js' %}"></script>

<script src="{% static 'myApp/videojs-record/dist/videojs.record.min.js' %}"></script>

<script>
// Handle audio record and upload
$(document).ready(function(){
    var player = videojs("myAudio", {
        controls: true,
        width: 600,
        height: 300,
        fluid: false,
        plugins: {
            wavesurfer: {
                src: "live",
                waveColor: "#36393b",
                progressColor: "black",
                debug: true,
                cursorWidth: 1,
                msDisplayMax: 20,
                hideScrollbar: true
            },
            record: {
                audio: true,
                video: false,
                maxLength: 60,
                debug: true
            }
        }
    }, function() {
        // print version information at startup
        var msg = 'Using video.js ' + videojs.VERSION +
            ' with videojs-record ' + videojs.getPluginVersion('record') +
            ' + videojs-wavesurfer ' + videojs.getPluginVersion('wavesurfer') +
            ' and recordrtc ' + RecordRTC.version;
        videojs.log(msg);
    });
    // error handling
    player.on('deviceError', function() {
        console.log('device error:', player.deviceErrorCode);
    });
    player.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log('error:', error);
    });
    // user clicked the record button and started recording
    player.on('startRecord', function() {
        console.log('started recording!');
    });
    // user completed recording and stream is available
    player.on('finishRecord', function() {
        // the blob object contains the recorded data that
        // can be downloaded by the user, stored on server etc.
        console.log('finished recording: ', player.recordedData);
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#submit').removeClass('disable-btn');
    });
    $('#submit').on('click', function(){
        var btn = $(this);
        btn.html('Saving...').prop('disabled', true).addClass('disable-btn');
        var myFile = new File([player.recordedData], 'audio.webm');
        var csrf = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
        var url = "{% url 'myapp:myurl' %}";
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('recorded_audio', myFile);
        data.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', csrf);
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: 'post',
            data: data,
            success: function(data){
                if(data.success){
                    btn.html('Re Submit');
                    $('.upload-comp').show();
                }
                else{
                    btn.html('Error').prop('disabled', false).removeClass('disable-btn');
                }
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
    });
});
</script>
</body>
```

*Views:*

```
class AjaxSaveAudio(View):
    """Use ajax to save audio sent by user."""

    def post(self, request):
        """Save recorded audio blob sent by user."""
        audio_file = request.FILES.get('recorded_audio')
        myObj = MyModel() # Put aurguments to properly according to your model
        myObj.voice_record = audio_file
        myObj.save()
        return JsonResponse({
            'success': True,
        })
```

Comment: Dear Vaibhav Vishal, Could you please have a look at my post update above ?

Comment: I will just post the code of how I am doing it, in a while.

Comment: Dear Vaibhav Vishal, Do you have your project on github? , it would be much easier if i could see your whole project in order to understand the whole thing :)

Comment: It is but it's private. Project is for my organisation. I can't show whole code publicly. Here too I have renamed name of model views etc. which you might have guessed

Comment: I used your template and view (i believe `my_Obj` should be `myObj` ) but when i open the template it just shows me inactive button `submit` and uploading bar. I loaded all of the required scripts (had to changed them because when i downloaded the videojs it was installed in the `node_modules` directory) so don't know what am i missing (probably some more brain cells lol)

Comment: yeah it will be myObj. In my css some elements are hidden by default like the upload complete span. The submit button should become active once you finish recording. Look at [this](https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record/blob/master/examples/audio-only.html) for a minimal audio recording example. It requires wvesurfer and few other stuff too make sure you added that. Also look at browser console for any errors if recording is not working.